# i am trying to get the name using a relationship

Tags: laravel

[image: image of category table]

[image: image of products table]here what I am trying to get the name of the category by using a relationship
here so far what I have done is I have defined a relationship in my product model as such

```
Public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsto(Category::class);
    }
```

I have also stored the field category id
in my products table

```
  Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('Category_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('code');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->double('price');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

also I have defined a relationship in my Category model such as

```
public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasmany(Product::class);
    }
```

ALSO I HAVE DEFINED Relationship IN
PRODUCT AS

```
Public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsto(Category::class);
    }
```

in my view I am trying to get the name of the category

```
    @foreach($products as $pro)
                            <tr>
                              
                            <td><img src="{{asset('uploads/maj/'.$pro->image)}}" class="img-circle" alt="User Image" width="50" height="50"> </td>
                            <td>{{$pro->category->name}}</td>
                            <td>{{$pro->name}}</td>
                            <td>{{$pro->code}}</td>
                            <td>{{$pro->color}}</td>
                            <td>{{$pro->description}}</td>
                            <td>{{$pro->price}}</td>
                            <td>{{$pro->quantity}}</td>
```

I am receiving the error

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

how can I get the name of the category ??
I am trying to get it like this but this is giving error

```
{{$pro->category->name}}
```

the category table row

```
  Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->String('Parent_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

my laravel version is 7 thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->foreignId('category_id')->nullable()->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('code');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->double('price');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

in model Product

```
public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'category_id','id');
    }
```

thin call products

```
$products = product::orderBy('created_at','asc')->with('category')->get();
```

you can chick if has relationship or not

```
 @if(! empty($pro->category)) {{ $pro->category->name }} @else <span>no category</span> @endif
```

Comment: the error remains the same .. trying to get property of non object

Comment: it show only no category where id is already passed in category id field

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one or more product doesn't have category or category_id is wrong.

you can use condition to check if category is not exist:

```
{{$pro->category ? $pro->category->name : "no category"}}
```

or can simply using null coalescing operator:

```
{{$pro->category->name ?? "no category"}}
```

if category is required you should prevent it by add table relation/foreign.

Comment: this show only no category where  as in my data base i have stored category id and i have defined the realtionship as well

Comment: Can you share your category and products table row?

Comment: i am updating it with the Category table row . u will find the product table row is already added to the question..

Comment: I meant row not column

Comment: i have added the picture of both categories and products table for ur ease ..

Comment: what is your DBMS? maybe it's case-sensitive, change `Category_id` to `category_id`

Comment: and also change `Public function category()` to `public function category()`

Comment: i am using laragon.yes it is case senstive i have tried both ways by making P as capital or making as non captial in boths ways it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this way :

```
(!empty($pro->category)) ? $pro->category->name : 'No category found'
```

Comment: bro the problem remains the same i am still getting the error trying to get property name of the non object ...

Answer (score 0):

I think You should define foreign key properly because your category_id not follow the coding standard. if you Category Model are in App directory you can use pass namespace like this

```
   Public function category()
   {
     return $this->belongsto('App\Category','Category_id','id');
   }
```

other wise :

```
   Public function category()
   {
     return $this->belongsto('App\Models\Category','Category_id','id');
   }
```